# How to disable line-too-long warning in SpaceVim

Tags: spacevim

I am using SpaceVim 1.0.0-dev with the following layers in my config:

```
[[layers]]
name = 'autocomplete'
auto-completion-return-key-behavior = "complete"
auto-completion-tab-key-behavior = "cycle"

[[layers]]
name = 'shell'
default_position = 'top'
default_height = 30

[[layers]]
name = 'lsp'
filetypes = ["python"]

[[layers]]
name = 'unite'

[[layers]]
name = 'git'

[[layers]]
name = 'lang#python'

[[layers]]
name = 'lang#markdown'
```

I tried supressing the line-too-long warning with

```
# noqa: E501
# pylint: disable=line-too-long
```

towards the top of the source file, but it does not work. I am very new to SpaceVim, and very confused by the whole layers thing... I cannot even find out which linter is used (although i suspect that pylint is used).

Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a new comer to Vim I strongly encourage you not to use SpaceVim and instead build your own config which matches your actual needs: you will learn much more about vim and will save _a lot_ of time debugging weird and complex configs you don't understand. Now to actually solve your problem you should ask your question on [their issue tracker](https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim/issues) there you'll get answers from people who actually made the tool and know how it works so you should get better and faster answers.

Comment: This has actually nothing to do with vim. Pylint ist a python linter, which has its own `.pylintrc.` file. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341746/how-do-i-disable-a-pylint-warning

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions. statox: I will look into the issue tracker. Doktor OSwaldo: my .pylintrc contains some adjustments that are ignored by the messages in vim (neovim to be specific), which is why I am trying to find out what is happening

Answer (score 1):

In SpaceVim, the default layer contains checkers layer which is using neomake, you can read `:h neomake` to config your pylint maker.

in neomake the default pylint confg is:

```
function! neomake#makers#ft#python#pylint() abort
    let maker = {
        \ 'args': [
            \ '--output-format=text',
            \ '--msg-template="{path}:{line}:{column}:{C}: [{symbol}] {msg} [{msg_id}]"',
            \ '--reports=no'
        \ ],
        \ 'errorformat':
            \ '%A%f:%l:%c:%t: %m,' .
            \ '%A%f:%l: %m,' .
            \ '%A%f:(%l): %m,' .
            \ '%-Z%p^%.%#,' .
            \ '%-G%.%#',
        \ 'output_stream': 'stdout',
        \ 'postprocess': [
        \   function('neomake#postprocess#generic_length'),
        \   function('neomake#makers#ft#python#PylintEntryProcess'),
        \ ]}
    function! maker.filter_output(lines, context) abort
        if a:context.source ==# 'stderr'
            call filter(a:lines, "v:val !=# 'No config file found, using default configuration' && v:val !~# '^Using config file '")
        endif
        call neomake#makers#ft#python#FilterPythonWarnings(a:lines, a:context)
    endfunction
    return maker
endfunction
```

make sure you have `.pylintrc` in your project root or home dir.